# How to call data from another sheet via a drop-down list on a Master sheet (Excel)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

so essentially say I have three sheets in Excel: "Company A", "Company B", "Main".

For the "Company A/B" sheets, in column A, I have information from Q1/2023. The different rows include: IRR, Committed capital, MOIC, Public companies, private companies etc. In column B, I have all the same information except that its for Q2/2023, then so on and so forth.

In the main sheet, I'd like to set it up so that in column A, I will have data from the "Company A" sheet. I will have a dropdown list on say Row B that'll allow the user to choose which Quarter's information they would like to view. Upon selection, the data will be "pulled" from the relevant quarter from the "Company A" sheet. For column B, this will be the same except that it will be pulling information from "Company B" sheet.

Would appreciate advice on resources and/where to get started! It sorta sounds intuitive, but I'm at a loss on how to begin.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What information is pulled on the "Main" worksheet when the user has selected the quarter? Is it just one metric (like IRR) or is it everything for that company for the quarter? If the second option, how would that work if company A is in column A and company B is in column B - where would the different metrics go?

Comment: @lisboakotor That would be the second option. The different metrics would just be "called" right under Company A in column A in different rows (i.e Row 3 is IRR, Row 4 is MOIC). So essentially depending on which Quarter I'm choosing, it will be pulling the entire column's data from that respective company's sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INDEX` and `MATCH` formula (a more advanced version of `VLOOKUP`) would do this.

`=INDEX($A$1:$D$5,MATCH($F$1,$A$1:$A$5,0),MATCH($F2,$A$1:$D$1,0))`

In this example, the `INDEX($A$1:$D$5` part is your range of data. The `MATCH($F$1,$A$1:$A$5,0)` part identifies the row associated with the quarter selected in cell F1 (this is where you would have the drop down). The `MATCH($F2,$A$1:$D$1,0)` part identifies the metric in column F. The whole formula will then return that metric's value for the quarter you have entered.

As the data is on a different worksheet (called "Company A"), you can use the same formula and just select the required cell range for the data, rows and columns. You can then do the same for the "Company B" column and data worksheet.

[image: Screenshot of Excel worksheet with an example of an INDEX and MATCH formula]

Answer (score 1):

Sample data
[image]

Set dropdown and formulas on "Main" sheet

- Step1: set dropdown list for A1, B1 (Data validation > List)

> Cell A1 - set list as `='Company A'!$A$1:$D$1`

> Cell B1 - set list as `='Company B'!$A$1:$D$1`

- Step2: set formula

> Cell A2 - set formula as `=OFFSET('Company A'!$A$1,ROW()-1,MATCH($A$1,'Company A'!$A$1:$D$1)-1)`

> Cell B2 - set formual as `=OFFSET('Company B'!$A$1,ROW()-1,MATCH($B$1,'Company B'!$A$1:$D$1)-1)`

- Step3: fill formual to A6, B6

---

Engjoy to get the data with a click.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the "Company A", "Company B", and "Main" sheets with the
   necessary data in "Company A/B" sheets as described in your
   question
2. In the "Main" sheet, set up the drop-down list for the user to
   select the desired quarter. Follow these steps:

   - Select the cell where you want the drop-down list to appear (for example, cell B1).
   - Go to the "Data" tab in the Excel ribbon.
   - Click on "Data Validation."
   - In the Data Validation dialog box, under the "Settings" tab, choose "List" from the "Allow" dropdown.
   - In the "Source" field, enter the options for quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3, etc.) separated by commas.
   - Click "OK."
3. Now, you'll need to use formulas to retrieve the data from the selected quarter in the "Company A" and "Company B" sheets based on the user's selection in the drop-down list.

   - In the "Main" sheet, enter the headers for your data in column A and B (IRR, Committed Capital, MOIC, etc.).
   - In cell A2 (assuming row 1 is for headers), enter the following formula to retrieve data from "Company A" sheet based on the selected quarter:
     =INDIRECT("'Company A'!A" & MATCH($B$1, 'Company A'!$B$2:$B$100, 0))
   - This formula uses the INDIRECT and MATCH functions to dynamically reference the appropriate cell in the "Company A" sheet based on the selected quarter.
   - Similarly, in cell B2, use the following formula to retrieve data from "Company B" sheet:
     =INDIRECT("'Company B'!A" & MATCH($B$1, 'Company B'!$B$2:$B$100, 0))
   - Adjust the range 'Company A'!$B$2:$B$100 and 'Company B'!$B$2:$B$100 to match the actual range of quarters in the respective sheets.
4. Test the drop-down list and see if the data in the "Main" sheet updates based on the selected quarter

- **Note 1**: Adjust the ranges and sheet names in the formulas as per your actual data layout.
- **Note 2**: Ensure that the data you want to pull is organized consistently in both "Company A" and "Company B" sheets to ensure the formulas work correctly.